# Mass of the fields in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, klein-gordon-equation

I understand that if I have an action 
$$S=\int \phi(\Box + m^2 )\phi$$
Then the field $\phi$ has mass $m$ since this is the pole of the propagator of $\phi$. Now If I have an action 
$$S=\int \phi_1 \Box \phi_2 + m^2 \phi_1^2$$ 
Then how do I interpret the mass of the field $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$?

My thinking was that If I find the equations of motion for $\phi_2$ then I have 
$$\Box \phi_1 =0$$
Which is a Klein-Gordon equation with no-mass so we interpret the field $\phi_1$ to be massless??

Thank you

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2). 1. Where are the integration measures? 2. The mass terms has the wrong signs. 3. The kinetic term in the 2-boson theory is not positive definite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to calculate the mass you need to go to an **eigenbasis**. Unfortunately, your theory is **ill-defined**: the kinetic term has a **negative eigenvalue**:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&1/2\\1/2&0\end{pmatrix}\sim \begin{pmatrix}1/2&0\\0&-1/2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Therefore, the Hamiltonian is unbounded from below and the model is simply **inconsistent**. If your kinetic term was positive definite, then you could simultaneously diagonalise it together with the mass term, and easily read off the masses.

Comment: I think your answer would benefit from being explicit about how you extracted these matrices from the OP's action.

Comment: @MartinC. It seems OP was able to figure it out by themselves :-)

Comment: Thank you @AccidentalFourierTransform . Just to make sure I understood it correctly. So you packaged phi_1 and phi_2 into a vector V={{phi_1,phi_2}} and rewrote the kinetic in terms of matrix V^T {{0,1/2},{1/2,0}} \Box V? I'm curicus if we can rewrite it as V^T {{0,1},{0,0}} \Box V, then eigenvalue of this would be {0,0}. which I guess would make the theory inconsistant anyway becase of zero kinetic term?

Comment: @user239970 Yes, basically. But recall that the kinetic term is a quadratic form, so its matrix representation is always the symmetric one. (The rest of representations are not canonical; their eigenvalues do not represent the principal axes of the transformation).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Ok thanks really helpful.